# How to integrate stripe in angular 8 with recurring payments(i.e subscription)

Tags: stripe-payments, angular8

I am trying to integrate Stripe with recurring payments.

I followed this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting

I understood i have to first create a checkout session and then i should pass the session id for further process.

I am able to create all the API's as per the document and i am able to get the session id too.

But i am stuck how can i integrate in Front end(i.e Angular 8) because thee doc is only provided for pure js.

Please let me know how to integrate to create checkout session and redirect checkout in angular 8.

One more doubt is, how to know already a customer or new customer before checkout session creation.

Please give me your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'; // this is typescript
```

```
stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_yourpublickeyshglhglglkdgjlrs')  

// Call your backend to create the Checkout session.
```

````
// When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.

async checkout() {
  const stripe = await this.stripePromise;
  const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    mode: 'payment',  
    lineItems: [{ price: this.plan, quantity: this.quantity }],
    successUrl: `${window.location.href}/success`,
    cancelUrl: `${window.location.href}/failure`,
  });

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include Stripe.js in your html base template as a normal script tag:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

Then, you'll need to initialize an instance of `Stripe` in the constructor or ngOnInit of your component.

```
this.stripe = Stripe("pk_text_yourpublishablekey");
```

Finally, when a button is clicked or on the event to trigger the redirect, you'll call `redirectToCheckout` with the sessionId that you've created on the server.

```
this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: sessionId });
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's throwing error for Stripe is not defined or stripe is not function

Comment: You might need to do something like: 

    declare let Stripe: any;

and ensure that the stripe tag was included.

Answer (score 0):

If 'Stripe is not defined' make sure that js.stripe.com/v3 is being loaded properly.
For Angular Install correspondent package

```
npm i @stripe/stripe-js
```

You can check chrome developer tools under Sources tab to check whether it loaded. Once its present, on your **component** load the PubApiKey:

```
  stripePromise: any = null;
  stripe: any = null;

  constructor(...)
  {
   ...
  this.stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_***')
      .then(res => {
        this.stripe = res;
      });
   }
```

And then wherever you return your session id from backend do the redirect:

```
  this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: stripeSession_id})
  .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
  });
```